# Delete duplicates from an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to delete the duplicates from an array of objects, but so far my algorithm gives me mistakes:

> request for member 'author' in '((Album*)this)->Album::songs',
>
> which is of pointer type 'Song*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)|

So this is the code:

```
void Album::deleteDuplicates()
{
    Song* current , *end = songs + top - 1;
    for ( current = songs + 1; songs < end; songs++, current = songs + 1 )
    {
        while ( current <= end )
        {
            if ( current->author == songs.author && current->title == *songs.title
                && current->year == *songs.year && current->length == *songs.length)
            {
                *current = *end--;
            }
            else
            {
                current++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What is `songs`? What is `top`?

Comment: @MrDuk songs is the array in class Album and top is the number of elements

Comment: In fact the compiler already has some idea on how to fix it. Note: `(*a).b` is the same than `a->b`. BTW, it seems you are modifying a `songs` member variable in the process, it does not look like a good idea.

Comment: Well, C++ have many nice [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). Why not [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the array (why are you not using [vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?) and use e.g. [a function to remove consecutive duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg to follow up, if the set is too large to sort, than you can get away with using std::unsorted_set (with a custom has operator). It wouldn't be perfect though...

Comment: OP, you need to POST this stuff in the question, people shouldnt have to scour your comments for basic questions such as this

Comment: This is horribly NOT `oop` if you want to be object oriented you should define a comparison operator and use that at least.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code the compiler error should go away.

```
if ( current->author == songs->author && current->title == songs->title
                             ^^^                                ^^^
    && current->year == songs->year && current->length == songs->length)
                             ^^^                               ^^^
```